# Compare two hashes with different salt

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, salt

I'm storing the salted hash of a credit card number in a database. What I'd like to be able to do is determine if two different entries in the same database correspond to the same credit card.

Specifically, let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two credit card numbers (which may or may not be the same). Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two different salts. If $H_1 = hash(C_1, S_1)$, and $H_2 = hash(C_2, S_2)$, I need a function, $f$, such that $f(H_1, S_1, S_2) = f(H_2, S_1, S_2)$ if and only if (with very high probability) $C_1 = C_2$.

Can this be done securely?

## Possible Solution

A friend of mine, who is a cryptographer, suggested the following:

Let $h(C, S) = g_1^{h_t(C)}g_2^{S}$ mod $p$, where $C$ is the credit card number, $h_t(C)$ is a "traditional" hash function, and $g_1$ and $g_2$ are generators that meet the Diffie-Hellman requirements, and $p$ is the corresponding prime.

If we do that, $f(H_1, S_1, S_2) = H_1g_2^{S_2}$ has the desired property.

A few questions:

1. Does this seem secure?
2. If I used a library, like the [Bouncy Castle libs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html), to pick $p$, $g_1$, and $g_2$, would it be safe for a non-cryptographer to code this up? In other words, how easy would it be for a non-cryptographer to screw up the implementation in a non-obvious way?
3. Advantages or disadvantages of this compared to the two other solutions proposed below. I tend to favor this because I'm familiar with Diffie-Hellman, while the others involve some techniques with which I am not familiar. Additionally, I suspect that there are more libraries for Diffie-Hellman since it's old and popular.

Comment: Not only can this not be done securely, but it also cannot be done. The entire purpose of salted hashes is to prevent this exact scenario.

Comment: I don't follow. I thought the purpose was to prevent rainbow table attacks. It seems that the existence of f doesn't necessarily mean a rainbow table attack is now possible. Note that f doesn't reveal the credit card number, it just tells me if C1 = C2. If I had a rainbow table, I'd still have to compute f(table entry, salt) for each entry in the database, which isn't any faster than just computing the salted hash of every possible credit card, right?

Comment: Assume some method exists to determine if $C_a = C_b$ given $H_a = H(C_a, S_a)$, $H_b = H(C_b, S_b)$. Generate a rainbow table of all possible $C_i$ mapped to $H_i = H(C_i, 0)$. Compare $C_a$ against all $C_i$ using the method we assume exists.

Comment: Salted hashes prevent rainbow attacks *precisely by* obscuring the relationship between any $C_a$ and $C_b$. It's the entire mechanism of action.

Comment: If there was a method to compare two salted hashes for equality of their inputs, an attacker would be able to build a rainbow table with the salt set to zero for all entries. He could then use that method to compare his rainbow table against your list of salted hashes.

Comment: Ack! I'm sorry, hit enter before I was ready and the comment didn't format right:

"Compare C_a against all C_i using the method we assume exists". I think this equates to the following:

`for each H_i in the DB we want to crack:  
   for each H_j in the rainbow table:  
       if f(H_i, S_i, 0) == f(H_j, 0, S_i):  
           H_i corresponds to C_j, break`
So we have to compute something for every user, CC# combination, which is the same amount of work we'd have to do if f() didn't exist.

If that's incorrect, could you perhaps show me some pseudo-code to demonstrate the attack? Thanks!!

Comment: (I'm coming back to this question since I was reminded about it when a quite similar question was asked.) ​ For your proposed solution, modular multiplication by $g_2^{-S}$ removes S. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as others have said, you would not be able to do with a standard salted hash function.

However, if you were use a specially designed hash function (that allows this specific comparison), then it would be possible.

Here is a proof-of-concept idea, to show that it is possible:

- Suppose $N$ was a large composite number of unknown factorization
- Let our hash function be $h( C, Salt ) = hash(C) ^ {2hash(Salt)} \bmod N$ (where $hash$ is a function that converts strings into large integers, in a way where hashes of different strings don't have obvious relationships).  The factor 2 is there to prevent the Jacobi symbol of $h(C, Salt)$ from leaking any information.

This hash function is one-way, because reversing it is the RSA problem, and that's hard if we don't know the factorization of $N$.

And, we can compare hashes $h_1, h_2$ with salts $Salt_1, Salt_2$, we just check if $h_1 ^ {Salt_2} = h_2 ^ {Salt_1} \bmod N$.

And, if you're wondering "how do we get a value $N$ which we know is hard to factor, well, we can just grab an RSA-challenge number of the appropriate size.

Now, I'm not really advocating this method (the "hashes" are quite lengthy); however it does show that it is possible in principle.

Comment: Nice. The only difficulty is indeed to find a hard to factor number $N$. The problem with selecting an RSA-challenge number is that it is hard to factor, but there is a trapdoor to your scheme: the factorization which is known to the person that generated the challenge (unless they forgot it, but can we be sure ?). In fact, this is a very nice question: is it possible to construct a provably hard to factor number in a way that does not construct the factors at the same time ?

Comment: @minar: That's exactly why I suggested the RSA-challenge numbers; that is, from a specific challenge dating started in 1991; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Challenge ); RSA Data Security (the company that generated the challenge) was quite clear at the time that they did not know the factorization themselves.

Comment: If you are paranoid enough, you may not believe them :)

Comment: Interesting idea. I haven't seen it formalized anywhere yet (although I have hardly read all cryptographic papers). Of course, it's not just that the hash will take a lot of space; it also means a modular exponentiation, which is relatively slow compared to performing a symmetric hash algorithm.

Comment: @owlstead: I'm not sure either if I got this idea from elsewhere, or it just occurred to me.  As for the performance, true, modexp is slow.  On the other hand, when hashing a password, we often deliberately choose a slow hash function (e.g. PBKDF2); the question then becomes "how do we make modexp slow enough" (and the answer to that would be to make $hash(Salt)$ a sufficiently big integer; possibly much larger than $N$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use an iteration count as in PBKDF2? That would take a lot less bits.

Comment: @owlstead: yes, it's be possible to iterate the modexp, but there's no reason to; bits are cheap.  It's quite possible to define $hash$ to generate (say) a one million bit output.  This means that $hash$ looks less like a standard hash function, and more like "the first million output bits of a PRNG seeded by $Salt$" -- there's no problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. The entire purpose of a salted hash is to obscure the relationship between identical plaintexts and their hashes. Hashes' resistance to rainbow table attacks also relies on this feature.

Let there be two plaintexts $P_a, P_b$, two salts $S_a$, $S_b$ such that $S_a \neq S_b$, and two salted hashes $C_a = H(P_a, S_a)$, $C_b = H(P_b, S_b)$. Assume there exists a function $f(C_a, C_b)$ that returns true if $P_a$ = $P_b$.

As an attacker, say you want to determine the plaintext $P_a$ for some hash $C_a$. Compute $C_i=H(P_i, 0)$ and store the pair $C_i$, $P_i$ for all possible plaintexts $P_i$ (known as a "rainbow table"). You can now attack the hash $C_a$ with your rainbow table by calculating $f(C_a, C_i)$ for all $C_i$. When $f(C_a, C_i)$ is true, look up the corresponding plaintext in your rainbow table.

Comment: Note that salted hashes aren't a great mechanism for storing credit card numbers, which only have around 48 bits of entropy. This is well within brute-force range. Best is a *slow* salted hash, like PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt.

Comment: Isn't computing $f(C_a, C_i)$ for all $C_i$ the same amount of work as computing $Hash(C_i, Salt)$ for all credit card numbers? In other words, I don't see how the existence of the rainbow table makes cracking things any faster if $f$ exists. What am I missing.

I definitely understand the concerns about using a fast hash and the small space of credit card #'s.

Comment: Notice that I said nothing about credit card numbers in my answer. This is a property of salted hashes themselves, not salted hashes when used on credit card numbers. Salted hashes *do not allow* what you are asking for. You indicated in your comments that you thought salted hashes prevent rainbow attacks. They *do*, and I am demonstrating that they do so precisely by preventing the sort of operation you would like to perform.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not getting this. I really do appreciate the time you're putting in here. As I understand it, without a salt you can use a rainbow table to do an O(1) lookup of a hash. Thus the time required to crack a single hash is O(1). In your response, you say that with $f$ you can crack a hash by computing $f(C_a, C_i)$ for all $C_i$ which is $O(n)$, where $n$ is the number of credit cards in the world. Without $f$ you'd compute the salted hash of every credit card numbrer for a complexity of $O(n)$. Thus, the time to crack appears the same with or without $f$. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that the answer has nothing to do with credit cards. Salted hashes *do* protect against rainbow table attacks. Whether or not rainbow table attacks are practical against your particular problem is completely irrelevant. The *means of action* by which they prevent rainbow table attacks is by preventing the existence of such a function $f(C_a, C_b)$.

Comment: Oliver is correct here. $\:$ It could be that $\hspace{.01 in}f$ is just as expensive to calculate as $h$ is. $\:$ For the standard use of rainbow tables, one can sort the final values of the chains to be able to do the lookups with a binary search, however, that doesn't help when searching for a hash in the table that satisfies something other than equality with $C_a$. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer The rainbow table diversion was in response to an earlier comment of his. "I thought the purpose was to prevent rainbow table attacks." Salted hashes *do* prevent rainbow table attacks, and the way they do it is by preventing the existence of the function he's looking for. If such a function could be found, salted hashes would not *in general* be a sufficient defense against rainbow table attacks.

Comment: The "way they do it is by preventing the existing of" an _easy-to-work-with_ way to compare the main hash inputs. $\:$ I believe the correct answer is "If $\hspace{.01 in}f$ can evaluated as fast as $h$ can, then slowing $h$ down further will only slow down precomputation.", which is far less definitive than "No, you cannot do this.". $\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering whether this is completely impossible if you are willing to interpret Hash in a very broad sense and use pairing-based cryptography. Stephen mentioned in a comment that the entropy of the credit card is low, so we should not rely too much on it in any solution.

What I am considering is the following. Assume for simplicity that we have access to a symmetric pairing $e$ on an elliptic curve $E$, $P_0$ a point that generates $E$ and a hash to curve function $H$. For a credit card number $C$ and a salt $S$ (with large entropy, ideally $S$ is a random integer modulo the order of the curve), compute and store the pair $(S\cdot H(C),S\cdot P_0)$, note that the salt value $S$ is **not stored**.

To verify that a given credit card number $C$ corresponds to a stored pair, check whether $e(S\cdot H(C),P_0)=e(H(C),S\cdot P_0))$. To check whether two distinct pairs correspond to the same $C$, compare $e(S_1\cdot H(C),S_2\cdot P_0)$ and $e(S_2\cdot H(C),S_1\cdot P_0).$

From a security point of view, you can still do exhaustive search on credit card numbers to find which $C$ correspond to a given pair, but since each verification is done via a pairing, it is not going to be really easy.

I know that this is out of the salted hash model suggested in the question, but depending on your exact requirements, it might be useful.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds really interesting. I don't know much about eliptic curve crypto, so I'm not sure if this does what I want, but this gives me a great place to start.

Comment: You could choose a database-wide triple workfactor,salt,memfactor and have H be given by $\hspace{.71 in}$ H(C) = maptopoint(scrypt(workfactor,salt,memfactor,C)) $\:$ . $\;\;\;$

Comment: If you use my suggestion for H, then the database-wide salt should be kept as secret as the pairs of group elements, so that one would need to compromise the database before one could start computing the scrypt values. $\:$ Independent of that, for minar's answer one would want to use a pairing that was _slow_ to compute (however, I'm not aware of any such pairings). $\;\;\;$

Comment: Concerning the speed of pairings, it really depends what you call slow. Using PBC library (http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/times.html) you might get 100 pairings/seconds. With scrypt, things are of course going to vary depending on your parameters, but with the litecoin settings speeds on CPUs are about 2000 hashes/seconds (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=66811.0).

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't be able to do this.

The whole point of using salts in your hashes is to prevent two identical objects from hashing to the same thing. You want those two elements to be hashed in a way that an attack won't be able to tell if they are the same or different.

You would have to be able to "undo" the hash with the given the salt to do what you want, which is obviously not something good functions let you do.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd have to be able to "undo" the hash. For example, *if* hash(C1 || S1 || S2) == hash(C1 || S2 || S1) you can do this but you can't necessarily reverse the hash. The above doesn't work because order is important in hashing, but it's not obvious to me that this is impossible.